# How to calculate the derivative of this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Here it is :

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left( \int_{\cos x}^{\sin x}{\sin \left( t^3 \right)\mathrm dt} \right)
$$

I've got the answer but I don't know how to start , what to do ?

Here is the answer : 
$
\sin \left( \sin^3 x \right)\cos x + \sin \left( \cos ^{3}x \right)\sin x
$

So first I calculate the primitive and then I derivate it. But I don't know how to integrate. Should I use 'substitution' method ? I tried but then i was blocked...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I understand from the comments that you are not completely pleased with the answers so far. That's why I try it (with a bit delay). Note that there is nothing new in this answer ...

All you need to know is the fundamental [theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) 
$$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F(x)$$
with
$$F(x) = \int^x_a f(t) dt$$
and the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Statement_of_the_rule) 
$$\frac{d}{dx} f[g(x)] = f'[g(x)] g'(x).$$

Your integral is given by
$$ \int_{\cos x}^{\sin x}{\sin ( t^3) \,dt} =F(\sin x) - F(\cos x)$$
with $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$$
and $f(t)=\sin(t^3)$.

Therefore,
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \int_{\cos x}^{\sin x}{\sin ( t^3 ) dt} \right]
 = \frac{d}{dx} [F(\sin x) - F(\cos x)]
 = F'(\sin x) \sin' x - F'(\cos x) \cos' x$$
$$ = f(\sin x) \cos x + f(\cos x) \sin x = \sin ( \sin^3 x) \cos x + \sin (\cos^3 x) \sin x.$$

Comment: Wow ! People on this website are amazingly helpful and nice !
Your explanations helped me a lot !
Honestly after reading (many times) the previous answers I understood this development . Now your answer confirmed what I've just understood !

Answer (score 6):

Look up [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t,x)\,dt = \frac{d b(x)}{d x}\,f(b(x),x)-\frac{d a(x)}{d x}\,f(a(x),x)+ \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\,f(t,x)\,dt$$

Comment: I don't know Leibnitz but apparently it must have a simpler development.

Comment: @CrazyJo: more simply, start off with $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \sin t^3 \text{d}t$.

Comment: To add to Mo's comment: you will want to differentiate $F(\sin\,x)-F(\cos\,x)$...

Comment: Well you do not need to analytically calculate the integral. $\int_{\cos(x)}^{\sin(x)} \sin(t^3) dt = F(\sin(x)) - F(\cos(x))$ where $F$ is the primitive of $\sin(x^3)$ i.e. $F'(x) = \sin(x^3) = f(x)$. Hence $\frac{d \left(F(\sin(x)) - F(\cos(x)) \right)}{dx} = \cos(x) \times f(\sin(x)) + \sin(x) \times f(\cos(x))$

Comment: Many thanks to you !

Answer (score 5):

First put the integrate as 
$\int_0^{\sin x} \sin(t^3)\mathrm dt - \int_0^{\cos x} \sin(t^3)\mathrm dt$
Then derivate the two items separately using the formula for the derivative of an integral with a varying upper integrating bound, e.g.,
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int_0^{\sin x} \sin(t^3)\mathrm dt = \sin((\sin x)^3)(\sin x)' = \sin((\sin x)^3) \cos x.$$

Hope this can help you.