# Getting the derivative of a function in an integral form

Tags: derivatives

$$g(x) =\int_x^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)dt %(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoun0.png)$$

How do i get the derivative of this function?

I know that it is not about finding the integral of the function because it is asking for the derivative. But how do I progress from here on out?

I have an answer but i just don't know if it is correct.
Basically i have

$-\cos(e^x) \sin x + \cos(\sin x) \sin x$

What i did was

$\cos(e^x) dt - \cos(\sin x) dt$

Which got me to

$-\cos(e^x) \sin x + \cos(\sin x) \sin x$

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations.

Comment: Where do all those $\cos e^x$ and $\cos(\sin x) \sin x$ come from? Did you make them up?

Comment: I followed the one from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37656/how-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-this-integral but I don't know if what I'm doing is correct.

Comment: If the derivative is w.r.t. $x$ then just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
g(x) &=\int_x^{\pi/2}\cos(t) \,dt \\
&= -\int_{\pi/2}^{x}\cos(t)\,dt \\
g’(x) &= -\cos(x)
\end{align}$$

First fundamental theorem of calculus with a twist

[image: fftc]