# Computing integral using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part I

Tags: calculus, integration

Question: Find the derivative of $\int^x_3{\sin^3t}dt$

Since $f(x)$ is a trig polynomial, $f(x)$ is continuous, so I applied FTOC I.

$\frac{d}{dt}(\int^x_3{\sin^3t}dt$)

= $F'(x)$

= $\sin^3x$                 (substituted x into t)

Apparently this is not the answer, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The question is $\int^x_3{sin^3t}dt$ ?

Comment: What's the question? $\int_3^x \sin^2(t) \, dt$ is not a question, it's just an expression.

Comment: Yes, that is the question

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I added a statement to the question.

Comment: @MichaelJohnson I think your answer is right .

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: how come when I integrate it using the integral-calculator.com it tells me the integral is cos^3t/3 - cos(t) | upper = x, lower = 3 (using FTOC II)

Comment: @MichaelJohnson The integral calculator is actually taking the integral, not the derivative.

Comment: @MichaelJohnson Your question is to finding the derivative of the integral .

Comment: For finding $\int^x_3{sin^3t}dt$ use $\sin 3x = 3\sin x -4\sin^3 x$ .

Comment: My understanding is kind of weak in this area, but the derivative of an integral is just another way of solving an integral, no? So shouldn't the answers be equivalent in some way?

Comment: The derivative of the integral is just the function .

Comment: See this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37656/how-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-this-integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are confused about what the problem is actually asking. 
According to your post, we want to evaluate $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big\lbrack\int_3^x\sin^3(t)dt\Big\rbrack$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we can "replace" the $t$ and $x$, to arrive at the answer
$$\sin^3(x)$$

However, if the question was to simply evaluate the integral 
$$\int_3^x\sin^3(t)dt$$
then we have 
$$\dfrac{\cos^3\left(x\right)-3\cos\left(x\right)}{3}-\dfrac{\cos^3\left(3\right)-3\cos\left(3\right)}{3}$$

The two procedures above are very different, since taking the **derivative** of an integral (i.e. applying $\frac{d}{dx}$) is to simply "undo" the integrating process and be left with the original function, whereas **integrating** the function is to find the antiderivative.

Comment: aH, thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that if
$$g(x) = \int_{a}^{f(x)} h(t)~{\rm d}t$$
where $a$ is any constant, then
$$g'(x) = h(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$$
Using this with the integral, $g(x) = g(x)$, $f(x) = x$, and $h(x) = \sin^3 t$.  We may now plug in these values.
$$g'(x) = \sin^3(x)$$
So, $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big\lbrack\int_3^x\sin^3(t)dt\Big\rbrack=\sin^3(x)$$